# Variable JavaScript en URL

Tags: javascript, variables, url

soy nuevo en la programación. necesito colocar el resultado de una variable JavaScript en el URL buscando a si la pagina web agregada ..

Arme mas o menos este código

```
    <script>  var URLimg ="www.google.com"; </script>
// abre una nueva pagina con el valor de la variable URLimg pero no lo coloca en el URL ni se dirige a la pagina web
<a href="javascript: document.writeln(URLimg);" target="_blank">IMAGEN</a>
```

me pueden indicar que función o estructura podria utilizar

Comment: Lo que buscas es `window.location.href=URLimg;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar `window.open` para abrir tu url desde `javascript`:

```
   <script>  var URLimg ="http://www.google.com"; </script>

   <a href="javascript: window.open(URLimg);" target="_blank">IMAGEN</a>
```

o desde una función:

```
 <script>  
    function myFunction() { 
      window.open("http://www.google.com"); 
    } 
 </script>

   <a href="javascript: myFunction();" target="_blank">IMAGEN</a>
```

Nota: Tienes que agregar el protocolo 'http://' al principio de tu `url` para que `javascript` lo interprete como una url nueva, ya que si no lo haces lo tomará como si fuera una subpagina de la actual.

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo que estos buscando es mas o menos de lo que se tratar este tema, resulta que tengo una pagina que genera un link en un acortador y el siguiente script lo que hace es que si entran desde un movil o tableta redifige segun el explorador, cuando ingreso a la url como escritorio imprime la variablebn pero si uso el mismo link y hago mi explorador como si fuese desde movil se pierde la varible y no imprime " + cuatro + " y en la url me sale undifined o sea en https://ejemplo-subdominio-undifined-dominio.com/test.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://ejemplo-subdominio- " + cuatro + " -dominio.com/test.html" + window.location.search
var uno =new String(window.atob(llegaron[1])); //Regreso
var dos =new String(window.atob(llegaron[2])); //UrlFin
var tres = (llegaron[3]); //Usuario
var cuatro =new String(window.atob(llegaron[4])); //Identificador
var cinco =new String(window.atob(llegaron[5]));  //Provedor
var seis =new String(window.atob(llegaron[6]));  //Provedor
var regreso = uno; //Regreso
var urlfin = dos;  //UrlFin
var idfb = tres; //Usuario
var detector = cuatro; //identifier
var lang = cinco;  //Provedo
var identifier = seis; //identifier
var enblanco = window.location.href; //En Blanco
var myString = new String(window.location.href);
var myArray = myString.split('*');
var regreso = myArray[1];
var urlfin = myArray[2];
var email = myArray[3];
var detector = myArray[4];
}
//-->
</script>
```